# Block redirects from specific methods asp.net

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config, episerver, episerver-find

There is an open redirect vulnerability in one of the nuget packages we use, it allows redirects in the form of: `https://example.com/find_v2/_click?_t_id=&_t_q=&_t_hit.id=&_t_redirect=https://www.google.com`
The culprit here is the `/find_v2/` endpoint taking the `_t_redirect` parameter.

Is there a way to block only redirects from the `/find_v2/` endpoint? We use Find for other operations on the site, but the redirect is not one of them. So I can safely block all redirects from Find.

I have already tried several versions of the following code in my web.config:

```
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Rewrite Location Header" preCondition="IsRedirection" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="http[s]{0,1}://localhost/find_v2/(.*)" />
          <conditions>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="http://{HTTP_HOST}/static/errors/GeneralError.html" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="IsRedirection">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3\d\d" />
          </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

A few other notes:

- I have successfully blocked ALL redirects from my site, but that is not a valid solution because our login page redirects back to the home page on successful login.
- In the "match" node, I cannot seem to use the 'url' attribute. I'm not really sure why, but that's why I'm using the 'pattern' one.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because unpatched (suspected) vulnerabilities should not be posted publicly.

Comment: @TedNyberg It is patched in a newer version of EpiFind - upgrading is just not an option for me. And the vulnerability is already publicly known. It is publicly available on multiple sites like Open Bug Bounty.

Comment: Ok! Close vote retracted. :)